# SDL2 Segfault when Creating a Renderer inside a Function

Tags: c, sdl

Using the sdl2 library, I'm trying to create the windows, surfaces and renderers inside a function but I keep receiving a segfault. I have my init_display function here:

```
void init_display (SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *surface, SDL_Renderer *renderer, int window_width, int window_height) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Cellular Automaton", 0, 0, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(surface);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
}
```

During execution, my program then calls a second function which uses the renderer just created, particularly with the `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor`

```
void draw_blocks (SDL_Renderer *renderer, int grid[], int x_blocks, int y_blocks, int block_size, int border_size, int window_width, int window_height) {
    int x, y;

    SDL_Rect blocks[x_blocks][y_blocks];
    for (y = 0; y < y_blocks; ++y) {
        for (x = 0; x < x_blocks; ++x) {
            blocks[x][y].x = (x * (block_size + border_size)) + border_size;
            blocks[x][y].y = (y * (block_size + border_size)) + border_size;
            blocks[x][y].w = block_size;
            blocks[x][y].h = block_size;
        }
    }

    for (x = 0; x < (x_blocks * y_blocks); ++x) {
        if (grid[x] == 1) {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
            SDL_RenderFillRect (renderer, &blocks[x % x_blocks][x / x_blocks]);
        }
        else if (grid[x] == 0) {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                SDL_RenderFillRect (renderer, &blocks[x % x_blocks][x / x_blocks]);

        }
    }
}
```

I ended up tracking the segfault through this very function `draw_blocks` and into `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor`. Here is my gdb output:

```
(gdb) run

Starting program: /home/arch/dev/cell/cell 

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".



Breakpoint 1, draw_borders (renderer=0xffffffffffffffff, x_blocks=80, y_blocks=80, block_size=8, border_size=1, window_width=721, window_height=721) at ./cell.c:112

112     SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0xFF);

(gdb) step

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (a=0xffffffffffffffff, b=127 '\177', c=127 '\177', d=127 '\177', e=255 '\377') at /home/arch/downloads/sdl/src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi_procs.h:365

365 SDL_DYNAPI_PROC(int,SDL_SetRenderDrawColor,(SDL_Renderer *a, Uint8 b, Uint8 c, Uint8 d, Uint8 e),(a,b,c,d,e),return)

(gdb) next

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor_REAL (renderer=0xffffffffffffffff, r=127 '\177', g=127 '\177', b=127 '\177', a=255 '\377') at /home/arch/downloads/sdl/src/render/SDL_render.c:1281

1281    {

(gdb) step

1282        CHECK_RENDERER_MAGIC(renderer, -1);

(gdb) step



Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x00007ffff7b0c410 in SDL_SetRenderDrawColor_REAL (renderer=0xffffffffffffffff, r=127 '\177', g=127 '\177', b=127 '\177', a=255 '\377') at /home/arch/downloads/sdl/src/render/SDL_render.c:1282

1282        CHECK_RENDERER_MAGIC(renderer, -1);

(gdb) up

#1  0x00000000004014b6 in draw_borders (renderer=0xffffffffffffffff, x_blocks=80, y_blocks=80, block_size=8, border_size=1, window_width=721, window_height=721) at ./cell.c:112

112     SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0xFF);

(gdb) up

#2  0x0000000000400d19 in main () at ./cell.c:38

38      draw_borders (renderer, x_blocks, y_blocks, block_size, border_size, window_width, window_height);

(gdb) up

Initial frame selected; you cannot go up.

(gdb)
```

I have a feeling its a problem with pointers and references but I don't have that much experience with those as of right now. From what I've read and thought about, I think the renderer being created with `renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(surface);` is just a renderer local to the init_display function and not being passed to the main function; `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor`is then trying to work with a renderer that is nonexistent but I may be wrong. I tried researching and attempting various fixes but I either end up creating a `renderer**` argument (`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` requires `renderer*`) or I end up entirely dereferencing the pointer and making it just `renderer`.How can I properly create the renderer in a function outside of main? Is this even the problem relevent to my segfault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with `init_display` function. In C, function arguments passed by value, so when you doing `window = SDL_CreateWindow` you actually changing function-local `window` variable, and value of variable that you originally passed to this function remains unchanged.

You can, however, pass pointer-to-pointer:

```
void init_display (SDL_Window **window, SDL_Surface **surface, SDL_Renderer **renderer, int window_width, int window_height) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Cellular Automaton", 0, 0, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    *surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(*window);
    *renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(*surface);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(*renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(*renderer);
}
```

(not a good code, uses pointer dereferencing too heavily, but that will work)

And then when you call this function:

```
SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Surface *surface;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
init_display(&window, &surface, &renderer);
```

Other code shouldn't require any changes.

You can also pass pointer to structure that have all fields you need and fill this structure from function. It is actually quite common when you have a lot of fields.

On a side note - if you only need renderer and have no interest in window or surface, why not just make renderer your function's return value? E.g. `SDL_Renderer *init_display(int w, int h)`

Slightly better version of the code above would cache pointers in local variables to eliminate unnecessary dereferencing:

```
void init_display (SDL_Window **window, SDL_Surface **surface, SDL_Renderer **renderer, int window_width, int window_height) {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Cellular Automaton", 0, 0, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Surface *_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(_window);
    SDL_Renderer *_renderer = SDL_CreateSoftwareRenderer(_surface);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(_renderer);

    *window = _window;
    *surface = _surface;
    *renderer = _renderer;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! After doing more research and working with pointers more, I can actually understand your modifications now. To answer your question, I do need the windows and surfaces, I just didn't make it clear I guess. I only wonder, if the code you posted isn't good code, how might one go about accomplishing the same task in a "good" manner?

Comment: @user3211355 I've edited my post, check it out. Difference is not very big, of course, but when you have a lot of small things it can become a big deal.